# Can not Set Activity Background

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I tried to set a full screen background for my main layout in android studio 2.3.3.

But the problem is
even when I convert my image for all the dpi's but stay cant see my image in my background
i use (android:background="Drawble/bg-main" ) not working
i use ImageView to set it but its not working and show this error (failed to instantiate one or more class)

I don't know what to do and I am very newbie in android developing thanks for helping me
see my screen shot to understand completely

**Screen Shot Error 1:**

[image]

**Screen Shot Error 2:**

[image]

Comment: change drawable name bg-main to bg_main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use capital letters or `-` in drawable image name. Just try to rename your image as bg_main and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Use `_` instead of `-`. So, your drawable should look like this `bg_main`/
P.S: never use `-` in XML naming

Answer (score 1):

```
    '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character:
 File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
```

Change your image name as bg_main for all. It will do.

Answer (score 1):

Because drawable name Bg-Main its not acceptable..

you r using **bg_main** special character not allow(B,-)